# How to mock multiple rows in a SELECT in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This might be a silly question but I have tried several things and can't obtain the result I want.

I am currently testing a very tiny API that consumes data from an SQL Server database. In order to test it I am using a stored procedure that "mocks" a row and returns it. Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ONE
    (@FRUITCODE VARCHAR(12))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        'BANANA' as NAME
    WHERE 
        @FRUITCODE > 0;
END;
```

This works fine to simulate one row, but I want to return more rows like this:

```
NAME
---------
BANANA
STRAWBERRY
MELON
```

I have tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TWO
    (@FRUITCODE VARCHAR(12))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        'BANANA', 'STRAWBERRY', 'MELON' AS NAME
    WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0;
END;
```

But that results in multiple columns, one is NAME and the others have a blank column name.

I also tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE THREE
    (@FRUITCODE VARCHAR(12))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 'BANANA' AS NAME
    WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0;

    SELECT 'STRAWBERRY' AS NAME
    WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0;

    SELECT 'MELON' AS NAME
    WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0;
END;
```

But this generates separate "tables" instead of a single one with multiple rows.

Lastly I tried

```
CREATE EPROCEDURE FOUR
    (@FRUITCODE VARCHAR(12))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        'BANANA' AS NAME,
        'STRAWBERRY' AS NAME,
        'MELON' AS NAME
    WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0;
END;
```

But this returns multiple "NAME" columns.

How can I return several rows? I am using SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: Search for "Table value constructors". This [link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/) should get you started. Scroll down to "Using a Table Value Constructor in a SELECT Statement" section.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the link, very interesting info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the `VALUES` table constructor, basically an inline 'invented' table, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on this.
It can also be done with `UNION ALL` but that is more verbose.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
        ('BANANA'),
        ('STRAWBERRY'),
        ('MELON')
) AS v (NAME)
WHERE @FRUITCODE > 0
```

Comment: At least explain what this functionality is called. Code only answers are frowned upon in SO.

Comment: @Alex Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is what I wanted. I also tried to add multiple columns like this: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('BANANA','1200'), ('STRAWBERRY','1400'), ('MELON','1500') ) AS v (NAME, FRUITCODE);`